# The value of attribute "name" associated with an element type "item" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: android

> java.io.IOException: Could not parse XML from android/accounts/annotations.xml

Anybody can help with the error above ?

Comment: Can you copy that part of the code?

Comment: <item name="android.accounts.AccountManager android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture&lt;android.accounts.Account&gt; renameAccount(android.accounts.Account, java.lang.String, android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback<android.accounts.Account>, android.os.Handler)">
    <annotation name="androidx.annotation.RequiresPermission">
      <val name="value" val="&quot;android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS&quot;" />
      <val name="apis" val="&quot;..22&quot;" />
    </annotation>

Comment: @Wengo Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56321219/edit) instead of putting code in comment, that's unreadable.

Comment: I am sorry...thanks buddy

Answer (score 7):

I have faced the same issue and there is two way you can fix it :

**1 - Cleaning the project** - (worked for me)

- In android studio , Build -> Clean Project

**2 - Checking the `api-versions.xml`** (in other case this should work)

Open your `api-versions.xml` available on

**C:\users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\api\api-versions.xml**

and then change this:

```
<method name="&lt;init>()V"/>
```

to this

```
<method name="&lt;init()V"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Upgrade your Gradle, that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem trying to build a legacy Cordova app. In my case it was during the release lint phase, so I skipped it using the `build-extra.gradle`

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false;
        checkReleaseBuilds false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I had a menu with hardcoded values of "<" and "=<" as menu items.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Well the error message tells you exactly the problem:

The name attribute of your `item` must not containt the `<` character. What else is there to say? In case you cannot read HTML: `&lt;` produces a "less than" character and `&gt;` produces a "greater than" character. So they are likely the reason for the error. But there are many other `<` and `>` charaters in the name attribute..try to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks for help, i will try to do as what you wrote...and update the result if  error still occurred after build